# Why does my Java Unit test result compare expected result with a memory location?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, junit4

I'm a beginner Java tester and I am trying to perform a data driven test in JUnit for practice. I want to check if the expected locator is equal to the actual locator that my 'UsernameVerification()' method generates. I currently have this block of code in the class that my test is referencing to:

```
    public void UsernameVerification() {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(LOGINPAGE);
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#username"));
        username.sendKeys("username@user.com");
    }
```

And this is my corresponding test class:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    DataDriven test = new DataDriven();
    test.UsernameVerification();
    assertEquals("#username", test);
}
```

When running the test, I get this error:

**org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <#username> but was: < DataDriven@6c372fe6 >**

**Expected : #username**

**Actual : DataDriven@6c372fe6**

I suspect the issue is that the JVM doesn't know what part of the UsernameVerification() method it's supposed to be comparing the locator to... or that 'assertEquals' is taking things a bit too literally with the 'equals'.

Is there a way that I can make the test pass by making 'assertEquals' compare the 'username' WebElement in my UsernameVerification() method, with the expected locator I've entered?

Sorry for the lack of proper terminology. I have researched a bit on how object references work in Java and I kind of understand a little but not sure how to fix this one.

Comment: `assertEquals` knows nothing about your `WebElement` or about `ChromeDriver`. When you say `assertEquals("#username", test);` you are asserting that one string is equal to another string. In this case ***literally*** `"#username"` and an instance of `DataDriven`. The comparison invokes `test.toString()` and `DataDriven` does not override the default `Object.toString()`. So your comparison is incorrect on **both** sides.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I doubt it even invokes `toString()`; I think it does `equals` directly and only `toString()`s the error output.

Answer (score 3):

Here, `test` is a reference to an instance of the `DataDriven` class, and `"#username"` is a string. A string cannot be equal to a username, for the same reason any given gun couldn't possibly be the same as any given grandma. These are WILDLY different kinds of objects so trying to compare the two results in an exceedingly swift: No, of course they are not the same.

The error message looks like a memory address but that's only because it is calling the default `toString()` method of DataDriven which prints itself that way. That address is not part of the comparison routine.

Check that `DataDriven` has an equals method. If it doesn't, write it, and if you can't, you can't use `assertEquals`, at all, with DataDriven instances. If it does, great - you can compare one instance of `DataDriven` with another.

Alternatively, query the DataDriven instance for some value and then check THAT against `"#username"`. For example: `assertEquals("#username", test.getUsername())`. I have no idea what `DataDriven` is or what it looks like, so I'm going with the hypothetical that it has a `getUsername()` method. You're looking for something like that (and ensure, of course, that it returns a `String` or you're still comparing guns and grandmas.

Comment: Thanks for the response. DataDriven is the class that I'm using to find the css selector. I want to check that the expected selector is the same as the selector on the webpage, which is why I use the assertEquals() method that comes with JUnit. So assertEquals() is not a method in my DataDriven class, only my DataDrivenTest class. The string "#username" is the name of the element on the page.